# I have 2 HTTP servers (apache and node) that I want to run on one machine, how do I forward to the appropriate service via domain name?

Tags: java, node.js, apache, ssl

I am running Apache serving a web app from a local folder and I want to run a node or java webserver to serve a static component of the site on a subdomain.

So the domain is xyz.com and i want www.xyz.com to go to apache and thing.xyz.com to go to the node (or Java) server.

They both need to be on port :443

[This is a diagram of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftHd0.png)
[Is this a good solution and where would I apply the SSL certificate?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDsZ9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one http server as a proxy server. That proxy server (for example Apache) listens port 443 and handles all the requests. It forwards all requests coming to host hing.xyz.com to node or Java server port (that listens some other port than 443) and handles requests coming to www.xyz.com it self.

Take a look at [Apache virtual host documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/)